# Toggling classes to a specific item in a .map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working with React Native, and I have set up a button where you can toggle the click and it'll add classes to it. However, if I have an array of items, its adding the class to all the items. I just want to add the class to the clicked button.

```
const Tags = props => {
  const [selectTag, setSelectTag] = useState(false);

  const tags = ['apples', 'oranges', 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'green peas', 'grapes'];

  // toggles the click
  const handleSelectTags = clicked => {
    setSelectTag(clicked);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View>
        {tags.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => handleSelectTags(!selectTag)}
            key={index}
            style={
              // when selectTag is true, adds styles.selected
              selectTag 
                ? [styles.tags, styles.selected]
                : [styles.tags, styles.notSelected]
            }>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tags: {
    paddingVertical: 3,
    paddingHorizontal: 9,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginRight: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  selected: {
    borderColor: 'green',
  },
  notSelected: {
    borderColor: '#ccc',
  },
});

export default Tags;
```

Not sure if what I have is the best way to do this, wondering if there's a more elegant way?

Comment: Do you only ever want one selected at a time?

Comment: @Galupuf no, i'd like the option to select multiple items at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have each `TouchableOpacity` manage it's own state by making it into a component. That way every time you click an item it's just updating itself :) This will allow you to have multiple clicked at the same time

```
const CustomComponent = props => {
  let [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => setSelected(!selected)}
      style={
        selected 
        ? [styles.tags, styles.selected]
        : [styles.tags, styles.notSelected]
      }>
     <Text>{props.item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

And then render this component in your map

```
{
  tags.map((item, index) => (
     <CustomComponent
       key={index}
       item={item}
     />
   ))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I went with. Also provided me a way to break out the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it correct

```
const [selectTag, setSelectTag] = useState('');

const tags = ['apples', 'oranges', 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'green peas', 'grapes'];

// toggles the click
const handleSelectTags = tag => {
  setSelectTag(tag);
};

return (
  <>
    <View>
      {tags.map((item, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleSelectTags(item)}
          key={index}
          style={
            // when selectTag is true, adds styles.selected
            selectTag == item
              ? [styles.tags, styles.selected]
              : [styles.tags, styles.notSelected]
          }>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose so give each button its own state.

**CODE:**

```
 // each button has his own entry
  const [selectTag, setSelectTag] = useState([false, false, false, false, false, false]);
  const tags = ['apples', 'oranges', 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'green peas', 'grapes'];

  // toggles the click
  const handleSelectTags = (index) => {
    var tmp = [ ...selectTag ]
    tmp[index] = !selectTag[index]; // update
    setSelectTag(tmp);
  }
```

**return**

```
    <>
      <View>
        {tags.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => handleSelectTags(index)}
            key={index}
            style={
              // update here to index of selectTag
              selectTag[index] 
                ? [styles.tags, styles.selected]
                : [styles.tags, styles.notSelected]
            }>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: output]

**DEMO:**

https://snack.expo.io/rJdZr!AHL